# how to solve the Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWoBM.png)

[inde.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ8Bk.png)

iam new in angular js  iwant a create a login page but routing not working  i got the  Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Your DI arguments mismatch in `App.config()`. You should remove `$rootScope` from function arguments or add `$rootScope` to the dependency array.